# Custom ID providers with Identity Toolkit?

Tags: authentication, google-identity-toolkit

Is there a way to add custom identity providers with the Google Identity Toolkit?

The default NASCAR doesn't support OpenID or Twitter. It appears that adding providers was possible in [an old version of the toolkit](https://sites.google.com/site/gitooldocs/customidps), and that page indicates that they hoped to make doing so easier in future versions, but I can't find any mention of this in the new docs.

When I try to look directly at the quick-start code to figure how to do this, it appears that the NASCAR page is put together in gitkit.js, which is loaded remotely. (that said, the code is minified and complex, so it's hard to interpret) This would suggest that there's no simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-identity-toolkit/CWJaq4D2Wlw) with what appears to be an ID Toolkit developer:

> Identity Toolkit does not support adding OAuth2 providers, and there is no easy workaround.

Also:

> We are currently experimenting with Twitter

So, it sounds like custom providers aren't yet an option (apparently even the original developers are having trouble adding Twitter), and they don't sound inclined to make custom providers an option:

> Our set of identity providers covers the majority of social login usage.